# Why does a WASM based web application work with desktop Chrome, not mobile Chrome on Android?

Tags: mobile-browser, uno-platform, webassembly

A WASM based web app built with Uno-Platform (a.k.a. Silverlight on Steroids) works with the desktop Chrome flawlessly, but it always crashes with the mobile Chrome on Android with the following screen:

[image]

The main file dotnet.wasm is 82 MB, but it is compressed to 11 MB for downloading. I used the desktop Chrome to debug the mobile version.  The debug console does not show any errors.

Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: The Application crashed somehow the browser tap in one way or another. But that could be anything. Shader run wild, to much memory, some specific complex code constellations. While wasm is perfectly running in Chrome on Android is see this on other ocassions even without any webassembly(or WebGL) involved. Most times deleting all the chrome app data helps.